# Text is too close to scroller. How to create a little bit space between scroller and text?

Tags: css

I have a div. When there is a big text then scroller comes on the right side of the div. Problem is that there is no  space between scroller and text and it looks bad. I want to make some space between scroller and text using css. How can i do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add some `padding-right` into your div to nudge the content out a bit.

Answer (score 2):

Add padding-right to your element:

```
padding-right:10px;
```

This will add a gap of `10px` between your text and scroller. If you have a fixed `width` on your element, you will have to reduce this by the same amount of the `padding-right` value to keep the same overall width.

E.g:

Before

```
div {
   width:500px;
}
```

With padding-right:

```
div {
   width:490px;
   padding-right:10px;
}
```